# “He is master of none” vs. “He is a teacher of history”

Tags: idioms, indefinite-articles

> John is [a] master of none.
>   John is a teacher of history.

I am wondering why the indefinite article is often missing in the first case but must be present in the second case. Is there any rule at work?

Comment: a better comparison would be *"John is a teacher of history"* because the word *master* is not the same. You could say *John is teacher of none* in the right context. It seems to me the concept of *none* has something to do with it.

Comment: "Jack of all trades, master of none" is a figure of speech.

Comment: Don't you think this would be better off in English Language Learning?

Comment: If you don't have an answer to this question, then it should stay here. It's beyond what a typical learner should learn in English classes.

Comment: you could even say *"John, teacher of none"* and means the same thing. I think it is because in this case *teacher* is a verb and a noun. Words that are noun only would not work. Spoken english grammar is not the same as written english grammar when it comes to *correctness*

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reason "master of none" frequently (but by no means always) appears without an indefinite article is that it is part of a longer proverbial expression—"[a] Jack of all trades and [a] master of none"—that takes several forms, some of which lack the indefinite article. The omission of the indefinite article is perfectly reasonable in contexts such as these:

> "**Jack of all trades, and master of none**," said Goodenough, with a sneer. [from *Popular Tales: Will* (1800), cited in [*The Macmillan Book of Proverbs, Maxims, and Famous Phrases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QHgbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22master+of+none%22&dq=%22master+of+none%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiljejyta3WAhXmxlQKHQZjAg4Q6AEIKDAA) (1948)]
>
> An old phrase goes, "**Jack of all trades is master of none**." [from [*Elements of Public Speech*](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5RZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22master+of+none%22&dq=%22master+of+none%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPk9Pxs63WAhXGs1QKHWbJDY8Q6AEIPDAE) (1929)]
>
> Though the **Jack of all trades is by reputation master of none**, the world of today is giving the Jack of all trades a high place when it reckons its values. [from [*Autocar Messenger*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MAk9AAAAIAAJ&q=%22master+of+none%22&dq=%22master+of+none%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPk9Pxs63WAhXGs1QKHWbJDY8Q6AEIODAD) (1928)]
>
> Above all it urged that they should not be "**jack of all trades and master of none**." [from [*The Federation of Master Printers: How it Began*](https://books.google.com/books?id=STxAAAAAIAAJ&q=%22master+of+none%22&dq=%22master+of+none%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiljejyta3WAhXmxlQKHQZjAg4Q6AEINjAD) (1950)

Because "master of none" is a familiar idiomatic or proverbial fragment, referring to someone as "master of none" rather than as "a master of none" immediately suggests the idiom to many listeners or readers. (This is not to say that "a Jack of all trades and [or *but*] a master of none" is an unusual form of the expression; it is quite common as well.) In contrast, saying that someone is "teacher of history"is slightly odd idiomatically: we expect that a particular person's vocation, identified without reference to a set phrase will include the indefinite article, as in "is a teacher of history" or "is a history teacher" (although alternatively you might say "teaches history").

The general pattern in U.S. English follows "is a history teacher"/"teaches history," while the oddball wording is "is master of none"—but again, that wording has a special status because it is associated with a centuries-old proverbial phrase.

Comment: In "master of none", "master" is being used as a title, like "king" or "emperor". (Think "John is King of England.") These traditionally do not receive the indefinite article (though they may receive the definite article). In "John is a teacher of history", OTOH, "teacher" is a common noun.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sentence:

> Aristotle was a student of Plato and teacher of Alexander the Great.

It's permissible to leave out the *"a"* before *"teacher"* because the *"a"* before *"student"* carries over and implies one before *"teacher."*
(Of course, you can also insert the second *"a"* before teacher.)

Now consider the full expression,

> He was a Jack of all trades and master of none,

which is where "master of none" is seen most often.
Here the *"a"* before *"Jack"* carries over to *"master"*. And people are so used to this form of the saying that they might easily use *"master of none"* even when they modify the first part.